# Rails get time zone based on time zone display name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, xero-api

I am fetching Timezones from an external API ([Xero](https://www.xero.com/)), but the display names returned here are different than those in `rails`. I am struggling to properly convert them to `rails` recognisable timezones.

Examples of timezones being returned by the API are:

- (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
- (UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague, etc.

The list of original timezones can be found [here](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI-Schemas/blob/master/src/main/resources/XeroSchemas/v2.00/Timezone.xsd).

Also, i have [this](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) URL, which provides information about converting them to rails way, but I am not sure how to do that as they are in comments.

Comment: Are you getting that full display string? Or are you getting the strings in the `value` attribute shown in the Xero timezone xsd you linked to?

Comment: See also https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI-Schemas/issues/56

Comment: Are you using [Xero's `organisation` API](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/organisation)?  If so, it looks like the answer to my first question is clearly that you're getting the `value`, not the element name.  Or are you using some other API?

Comment: @MattJohnson yes, I am getting the value, but I can easilly map these to diplay names. I do not think that these values are any easier to convert to rails timezone than display names?